# How to get de last id for upload images with AjaxFileUpload?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, foreign-keys

I'm trying to join 2 tables by using C# and SQL Server on Visual Studio 2017.
The first table adds onClickEvent in Planuri. In the second table, AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete must add the pictures in SQL. How to use the foreign key (DorintaId) to upload images in ImaginiWishlist?

I've tried after the first ExecuteNonQuery: Int32 DorintaId=(Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

```
{String CS= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BudgetDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Planuri values('" + tbNumeDorinta.Text + "','" + tbTarget.Text + "','" + tbPretE.Text + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

and this is the event with Ajax:

{

```
    if (AjaxFileUpload1.HasAttributes)
    {

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Wishlist/" + fileName));
        String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BudgetDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ImaginiWishlist(Nume,Extensie,DorintaId) values(@Nume,@Extensie,@DorinaId)", con);


            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", fileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extensie", extension);


           // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DorintaId", DorintaId);

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

EDIT: 
{

```
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FileName);

    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BudgetTrackDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ImaginiWishlist(Nume,Extensie,DorintaId) values(@Nume,@Extensie,@DorintaId);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con))

        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {

                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", fileName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extensie", extension);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DorintaId",SqlDbType.Int,4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Each row from Planuri to have associate the uploaded image/s from ImaginiWishlist.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

after the insert statement where you want to return the Id of the inserted row and use ExecuteScalar()

Please refer to the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Your insert into `ImaginiWishlist` is much better as you're using parameters, you should do the same for `Planuri` and pass your three values as parameters. Also, I believe you're missing the list of column names in your insert statement for `Planuri`, you need to add the list of columns you are updating in your insert, just before `values`.

I will have to guess, as I don't know the structure of your table, but something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Planuri (NumeDorinta, Target, PretE) values('" + tbNumeDorinta.Text + "','" + tbTarget.Text + "','" + tbPretE.Text + "'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
```

and to add the values as parameters, I'm guessing your table has got a datetime for tbTarget and a float for tbPertE, so you would do something like this for the date time, where you would change the `CultureInfo` to the correct one for your country

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetDate", Convert.ToDateTime(tbTarget.Text, CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-GB")))
```

or you could try this if your date in tbTarget.Text is in a specific format, where you would change "dd/MM/yyyy" to be your format.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetDate", DateTime.ParseExact(tbTarget.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.Invariant))
```

For the float, try using:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PretE", Convert.ToSingle(tbPretE.Text))
```

Comment: Dupre, thanks for your help. I tried to pass the values in Planuri, but I can not convert the datetime(tbTarget) and float(PretE) types.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added more information as there was too much for the comment

Answer (score 0):

You could add @ID to the params collection and then retrieve it like this:

```
{
int dorintaId = 0


     String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BudgetDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
     using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Planuri values('" + tbNumeDorinta.Text + "','" + tbTarget.Text + "','" + tbPretE.Text + "'); ; SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      dorintaId = (int) cmd.Parameters["@ID"].value;
     }
```

We now could get `dorintaId` and use it in `ImaginiWishlist` table:

```
{
    if (AjaxFileUpload1.HasAttributes)
    {

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Wishlist/" + fileName));
        String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BudgetDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ImaginiWishlist(Nume,Extensie,DorintaId) values(@Nume,@Extensie,@DorintaId);", con);


            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", fileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extensie", extension);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DorintaId", dorintaId);

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: It's not working. :( The data is not insert into table ImaginiWishlist.

Comment: @piglet see the revision

Comment: Thank for the solutions but they don't work again. ID is DorintaId, right? I debugg the code and the value of DorintaId is 'Extension'.

Comment: Please don't change `@ID` to `@DorianId`, it's a different thing, try to just copy paste above code

Comment: I run the code above, and the bug is: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DorintaId', table ImaginiWishList.

Comment: Is DorintaId AutoIncrement Integer?

Comment: I don't think it is. The primary key from ImaginiWishList [ImagId] is autoincrement. The both can not be.

Comment: error: DorintaId does not exist in current context. This line 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DorintaId", DorintaId);'

Comment: What is `DorintaId` actually? does the system need it? where is it come from?

Comment: DorintaId is the foreign key. It is primary key in Planuri and foreign key in the second table ImaginiWishlish.

Comment: @piglet please see the revision

Comment: This is the error at the line 'dorintaId = cmd.Parameters["@ID"].value; ' : Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Cast to int `dorintaId = (int) cmd.Parameters["@ID"].value;`

Comment: I did. But in the AjaxFile Upload event, is not recognized DorintaId.

Comment: Do dorintaId in first source code return last insert id ?  If it result the right id, then you could pass the data to second source code. I couldn't answer your last question because I don't know how you structure your source code.

Comment: No, dorintaId is 0 after ExecuteQuery... I don't have an ideea why it does not increment.

Comment: Should I create a stored procedure?